# Is it possible to write to a specifiv Partition on a Kafka-Topic with MQTT-Proxy from Confluent?

Tags: apache-kafka, mqtt, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

Maybe someone can help me solving a little Problem. Is there a way to configure a Partitioning by Key with the Producer built-in the MQTT-Proxy from Confluent?

There's only a Topic-Mapping-Property, but I've not found how to use the MQTT-Proxy with a Topic partitioned by Key. Can I include the Key for the Kafka-Protocol within the MQTT-Message?

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...sorry. Found the part:

> Since topic naming rules in Kafka are much stricter than in MQTT, not
> every MQTT topic may map to a Kafka topic. Therefore, an **MQTT topic is**
> **represented by a message key** in Kafka, and a single Kafka topic may
> contain messages for multiple MQTT topics.

https://www.confluent.de/blog/iot-streaming-use-cases-with-kafka-mqtt-confluent-and-waterstream/